# Android Date Time picker in one dialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design, datetimepicker

I am using material `Date` `Time` picker for my Android app. But I want to combine the `Date` and `Time` picker in one dialog.

I am following [this one](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#implement-an-ontimesetlistenerondatesetlistener). But I need to select the time right after the date selection.

Please suggest possible way to do this one.

Comment: you can check this https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker

Answer (score 40):

You can call `TimePicker` after `DatePicker` set Date. Like this..

```
    String date_time = "";
    int mYear;
    int mMonth;
    int mDay;

    int mHour;
    int mMinute;

    et_show_date_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_show_date_time);
    btn_set_date_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_date_time);

    btn_set_date_time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datePicker();

        }
    });
```

Date Picker:

```
    private void datePicker(){

    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    date_time = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                   //*************Call Time Picker Here ********************
                   tiemPicker();
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
       datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Time Picker

```
 private void tiemPicker(){
    // Get Current Time
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {

                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;

                    et_show_date_time.setText(date_time+" "+hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

--

Comment: Have you tested this code? This doesn't seem to be working for me. Upon selection of date, it is not calling the timepicker.

Answer (score 33):

### Kotlin

Here's the tested Kotlin code for combining the `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` together. It becomes simpler because of the support of the closures in Kotlin. The following function should be placed in your `Fragment` or `Activity`. The `requireContext()` method is a member of `Fragment`. If you are using `Activity`, use `applicationContext` instead.

```
private fun pickDateTime() {
    val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
        TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
            val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
            doSomethingWith(pickedDateTime)
        }, startHour, startMinute, false).show()
    }, startYear, startMonth, startDay).show()
}
```

Call the above function in `onClickListener` of your button as following:

```
button.setOnClickListener { pickDateTime() }
```

That's it!

If you want to show clock in 12 hour or 24 hour format depending on user's settings, replace `false` with `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(requireContext())`

Comment: This works like a charm , but you need to add +1 to month to get the correct value

Answer (score 15):

Try this code :

CustomDateTimePicker.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by admin on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements View.OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

    private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

    private Calendar calendar_date = null;

    private Activity activity;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

    private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

    public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
                                ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
        activity = a;
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                resetData();
            }
        });

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    }

    public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
        linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
        btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
        btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
        btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
        btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
        btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
        btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
        linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
        viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
        timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectedHour = hourOfDay;
                selectedMinute = minute;
            }
        });

        viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
        viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

        LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
        linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_set = new Button(activity);
        btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_set.setText("Set");
        btn_set.setId(SET);
        btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
        btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
        linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

        linear_child.addView(linear_top);
        linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
        linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

        linear_main.addView(linear_child);

        return linear_main;
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

            datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

            dialog.show();

            btn_setDate.performClick();
        }
    }

    public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
        this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
        if (calendar != null)
            calendar_date = calendar;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.setTime(date);
        }
    }

    public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
                && year < 3000) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
        }

    }

    public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
        if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = true;
        }
    }

    public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
                                      boolean isAM) {
        if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (hourIn12Format == 12)
                hourIn12Format = 0;

            int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

            if (!isAM)
                hourIn24Format += 12;

            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = false;
        }
    }

    public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
        is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
    }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                          Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                          String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int day,
                          String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                          int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

        public void onCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case SET_DATE:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);

            if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != datePicker) {
                viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            }
            break;

        case SET_TIME:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
            if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() == datePicker) {
                viewSwitcher.showNext();
            }
            break;


            case SET:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                    int year = datePicker.getYear();
                    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


                    calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                            selectedMinute);

                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                            calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                            getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
                }
                if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;

            case CANCEL:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            date in String
     * @param fromFormat
     *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
     *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
     * @param toFormat
     *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
     *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
     *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
     * @return formatted date
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
                                     String toFormat) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
            Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }

    private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
        int hourIn12Format = 0;

        if (hour24 == 0)
            hourIn12Format = 12;
        else if (hour24 <= 12)
            hourIn12Format = hour24;
        else
            hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

        return hourIn12Format;
    }

    private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
        String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
                : "PM";
        return ampm;
    }

    private void resetData() {
        calendar_date = null;
        is24HourView = true;
    }

    public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
        if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
            return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    }
}
```

In your Activity :

MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

     CustomDateTimePicker custom;
Button btnEventDateTime;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btnEventDateTime = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEventDateTime));
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
                    new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                                          Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                                          String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int day,
                                          String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                                          int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                                          String AM_PM) {
    //                        ((TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEventDateTime))
                            edtEventDateTime.setText("");
                            edtEventDateTime.setText(year
                                    + "-" + (monthNumber + 1) + "-" + calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + " " + hour24 + ":" + min
                                    + ":" + sec);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }
                    });
            /**
             * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
             * false
             */
            custom.set24HourFormat(true);
            /**
             * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
             */
            custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            btnEventDateTime.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            custom.showDialog();
                        }
                    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: but it is showing in pink color, where can I change the color, or set the theme please help.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava now you can change colors also, you have to change in DialogTheme. see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042997/3994127

Comment: just what I was looking for, but when I try to `setDate` with a Date, the minutes still being the current time minutes. any idea why?

Comment: @AlexLordMordor can you pls elaborate more in details?

Comment: I nottice that with your answer opens the dialog using default or first established date and time using current, your class have a function to set a date and time using a `Date` value, BUT! this works well except for the minutes, the minutes still being the current or default.
I did a little hack adding a Date variable `hacked_date` that initalizes with the `setDate` function, and instead of doing `timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);` in the `showDialog()` I used `timePicker.setCurrentMinute(hacked_date.getMinutes());`... Seems to be a bug in the Calendar.MINUTE value

Comment: Ohhh That's Great. Thank you @AlexLordMordor.

Answer (score 2):

Googled this problem and found usefull Enamul Haque's answer. Modified his code little bit and got this result. Its quick solution and will be improved, but works nice)

```
public class DateTimePicker {

    @NonNull
    private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    @Nullable
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    @Nullable
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    @Nullable
    private ResultCallback<Date> dateResultCallback;

    public void showDialog(@NonNull Context context, long time) {
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        closeDialogs();
        showDatePicker(context);
    }

    @Nullable
    public ResultCallback<Date> getDateResultCallback() {
        return dateResultCallback;
    }

    public void setDateResultCallback(@Nullable ResultCallback<Date> dateResultCallback) {
        this.dateResultCallback = dateResultCallback;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private void closeDialogs() {
        if (datePickerDialog != null) {
            datePickerDialog.dismiss();
            datePickerDialog = null;
        }
        if (timePickerDialog != null) {
            timePickerDialog.dismiss();
            timePickerDialog = null;
        }
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            timePicker(view.getContext());
        }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            if (dateResultCallback != null) {
                dateResultCallback.onResult(calendar.getTime());
            }
        }
    };

    private void showDatePicker(@NonNull Context context) {
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                dateSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

    private void timePicker(@NonNull Context context) {
        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context,
                timeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public void release() {
        closeDialogs();
        dateResultCallback = null;
    }

}
```

Dialogs calls via method showDialog(...), possible to release object when it not need anymore (in onDestroy() in activity f.e). 
And again - thanks Enamul Haque for idea.

Comment: ResultCallback<Date> dateResultCallback its simple interface from my project `public interface ResultCallback<Result> {

    void onResult(@Nullable Result result);

}`

Comment: Hi Ruslan, 
How to prevent previous days and times entry in this coding snippet

Comment: Umasankar, you can set datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000); or something like this

Answer (score 2):

This answer is basically an improvement in answer given by @Mayur Patel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604615/3994127

**CustomDateTimePicker.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import com.gotrack.gotrack.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CustomDateTimePicker implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Calendar calendar_date = null;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private AppCompatButton btnDate, btnTime;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

    private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

    public CustomDateTimePicker(Context context,
                                ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_time_picker);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                resetData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setView() {
        btnDate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTime = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_set).setOnClickListener(this);
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(this);
        viewSwitcher = dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_switcher);
        datePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        timePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

        btnDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTime.setOnClickListener(this);

        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

        datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

        btnDate.performClick();
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            dialog.show();

            setView();
        }
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
        this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker dismissDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();

        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setDate(Calendar calendar) {
        if (calendar != null)
            calendar_date = calendar;
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setDate(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.setTime(date);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
                && year < 3000) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
        if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = true;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
                                                      boolean isAM) {
        if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (hourIn12Format == 12)
                hourIn12Format = 0;

            int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

            if (!isAM)
                hourIn24Format += 12;

            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = false;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public CustomDateTimePicker set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
        is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
        return this;
    }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
        void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                   Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                   String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int day,
                   String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                   int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

        void onCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_date:
                btnTime.setEnabled(true);
                btnDate.setEnabled(false);

                if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != datePicker) {
                    viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btn_time:
                btnTime.setEnabled(false);
                btnDate.setEnabled(true);
                if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() == datePicker) {
                    viewSwitcher.showNext();
                }
                break;


            case R.id.btn_set:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                    int year = datePicker.getYear();
                    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    selectedHour = timePicker.getHour();
                    selectedMinute = timePicker.getMinute();
                } else {
                    selectedHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                    selectedMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                }

                    calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                            selectedMinute);

                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                            calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                            getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
                }
                if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_cancel:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param date       date in String
     * @param fromFormat format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
     *                   09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
     * @param toFormat   format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
     *                   required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
     *                   <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
     * @return formatted date
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
                                     String toFormat) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }

    private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);

        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);

        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);

        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);

        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
        int hourIn12Format = 0;

        if (hour24 == 0)
            hourIn12Format = 12;
        else if (hour24 <= 12)
            hourIn12Format = hour24;
        else
            hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

        return hourIn12Format;
    }

    private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
        return (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
                : "PM";
    }

    private CustomDateTimePicker resetData() {
        calendar_date = null;
        is24HourView = true;
        return this;
    }

    public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
        if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
            return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    }
}
```

**date_time_picker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/set_date"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_time"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="@string/set_time"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_set"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/set"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_set" />

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_set"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_date">

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/time_picker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
        </ViewSwitcher>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**DialogTheme style**

```
<style name="DialogTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Calling code**

```
new CustomDateTimePicker(context,
        new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                              Date dateSelected, int year,
                              String monthFullName,
                              String monthShortName,
                              int monthNumber, int date,
                              String weekDayFullName,
                              String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                              int hour12,
                              int min, int sec, String AM_PM) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        }).set24HourFormat(true).setDate(Calendar.getInstance())
        .showDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select the time right after the date selection you can simply show `TimePickerDialog` automatically after date is selected. This is the easiest way.

While you have listener that is fired when date is selected with selected date, you can simply pass that selected date to `TimePickerDialog` and with a few customization in `mdtp_time_picker_dialog.xml` you can add a `TextView` to show the selected text.

Another option is merging `mdtp_time_picker_dialog.xml` and `mdtp_date_picker_dialog.xml` that are root layouts for date picker dialog and time picker dialog. You can set time picker part visibility as `GONE` and switch the visibility when you want to switch pickers.

The second solution is more difficult to implement because in addition to layouts, you have to merge all controls and listeners.

If you want the user to see both of the pickers, I think you actually need to design a new view yourself. That library layouts is not suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple code.. I'm using this code in my Project..

```
final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
date = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            // Log.v(TAG, "The choosen one " + date.getTime());
                            // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The choosen one " + date.getTime(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            datetime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a").format(date.getTime()));
                        }
                    },currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();

                }
            }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(currentDate.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Getting an error with your code:Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get `Date` And `Time` One By One Using `Pickers` In Android.

```
Calendar getDate = Calendar.getInstance();

         cDay = getDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
         cMonth = getDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         cYear = getDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

         timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DesignActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                final String AM_PM ;

                if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                    hourOfDay -= 12;
                    AM_PM = "pm";
                } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                    hourOfDay += 12;
                    AM_PM = "am";
                } else if (hourOfDay == 12)
                    AM_PM = "pm";
                else
                    AM_PM = "am";

                hour1 = hourOfDay;
                minutes1 = minute;

                DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(DesignActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                        cYear = year;
                        cMonth = month;
                        cDay = dayOfMonth;

                        editText.setText(hour1 + ":" +minutes1 + AM_PM  + "     " + cDay + "/" + cMonth + "/" + cYear);

                    }
                },cYear,cMonth,cDay);

                datePicker.show();

            }
        },hour1,minutes1,false);

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }
});
```

If You Will Need More Explanation About 
[Click This](https://theandroidcodings.blogspot.com/2019/04/time-and-date-pickers-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @[Yogesh Umesh Vaity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449808/5563931), I made an object for showing a DateTimePicker in Kotlin.

```
class DateTimePicker(val context: Context, var pickTime:Boolean = false, var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),
                     var callback: (it : DateTimePicker) -> Unit) {

    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun getFormat(format : String) : String{
            when(format){
                "d" -> return "dd/MM/yyyy"
                "t" -> return "HH:mm"
                "dt" -> return "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
            }
            return "dd/MM/yyyy"
        }
    }

    fun show(){
        val startYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val startMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val startHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val startMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        DatePickerDialog(context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            if(pickTime) {
                TimePickerDialog(context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                    calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
                    callback(this)
                }, startHour, startMinute, true).show()
            } else {
                calendar.set(year,month,day)
                callback(this)
            }
        }, startYear, startMonth, startDay).show()
    }

    fun showTime(){
        val startYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val startMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val startHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val startMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        TimePickerDialog(context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
            calendar.set(startYear, startMonth, startDay, hour, minute)
            callback(this)
        }, startHour, startMinute, true).show()
    }
}
```

You could use the object from your Activity like this:

```
// Open Date Picker only and set an EditText
DateTimePicker(this){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(DateTimePicker.getFormat("d"), Locale.getDefault())
    editText.setText(sdf.format(it.calendar.time))
}.show()

// Open Date Picker then Time picker and set an EditText
DateTimePicker(this, true){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(DateTimePicker.getFormat("dt"), Locale.getDefault())
    editText.setText(sdf.format(it.calendar.time))
}.show()

// Open Time Picker only and set an EditText
DateTimePicker(this){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(DateTimePicker.getFormat("t"), Locale.getDefault())
    editText.setText(sdf.format(it.calendar.time))
}.showTime()

// Use your own calendar object if you prefer to use your pre-configured calendar
val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1995)
DateTimePicker(this, false, myCalendar){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(DateTimePicker.getFormat("d"), Locale.getDefault())
    editText.setText(sdf.format(it.calendar.time))
}.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is java version of @yogesh answer

```
private void createDateTimePickerDialog() {
    Calendar currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    new DatePickerDialog(this, (datePicker, year, month, day) -> new TimePickerDialog(ProjectDatesActivity.this, (timePicker, hour, minute) -> {
        Calendar pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);
        String date = day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year;//since month starts from 0 we need to +1
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Date date_form = sdf.parse(date);
            finish_date = sdf.format(Objects.requireNonNull(date_form));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String time = hour + ":" + minute;
        DateTimeTv.setText(date + " " + time);
    }, startHour, startMinute, false).show(), startYear, startMonth, startDay).show();
}
```